# How to order date by DAY in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have a page where I'm showing the birthdays of the collaborators. right now I'm querying  with `@Collaborators = Collaborator.where("extract(month from birth_date) = ? AND flag_removed = 0", currentMonth)` and displaying the collaborator birthdate as dd/mm/yyyy.

How can I query these collaborators and order them by date of the month? Right now I can order them by the oldest to the youngest, but I want to order them by the day of the month they have their birthdays.

In other words, instead of ordering dd/mm/yyyy I want to order dd/mm

how could that be done?

Comment: You can use the SQL function `DAY(<date>)`

Comment: I need to order by day, not get the day...

Comment: But it actually worked!!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I used the SQL function DAY() to order

```
@Collaborators = Collaborator.where("extract(month from birth_date) = ? AND flag_removed = 0", currentMonth).order(' DAY(birth_date)')
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, I use postgres

```
Collaborator.order("to_char(birth_date, 'MM-DD')")
```